# Initial-value problem by separation of variables

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, dynamical-systems, initial-value-problems

Sorry if this is too easy, but I have really been struggling with this. I have been asked to solve the initial-value problem by separation of variables and determine the maximum time interval of existence of the solutions for $$\dot{x}=x(2-x)^2,\, x(0)=1$$
When integrating, I got $$t=\frac{1}{4}\,\log\left( \frac{x(t)}{2-x(t)}\right)-\frac{1}{2(2-x(t))}+\frac{1}{2}$$
But I need to get an explicit equation for $x(t)$ and I cannot find a way to get it. Should I make a change of variables? Also, I would say that the maximum interval of existence of the solution is $(-\infty,\infty)$?

Comment: @Moo - the OP is looking for an interval in $t$, not $x$. But that same $0 < x < 2$ range (forced by the asymptotes, not the log argument since the full antiderivative of $1/x$ is $\log |x| + C$) does indeed correspond to $t$ ranging over all of $(-\infty, \infty)$, and since $x$ is a strictly iincreasing function of $t$, it is invertible.

Comment: You *might* be able to use Lambert's $W$ function to get a closed form. but I doubt it will be useful to you. I echo Moo's question: are you sure you need a closed form? Most DEs do not have closed form solutions. For mathematical uses, usually just the existence of a solution is enough. For calculation, generally a Taylor series, or some estimation scheme is actually far easier to calculate values than closed form solutions involving esoteric functions.

Comment: @Moo, I need it because in my class of dynamical systems we are studying the how the flow changes as time goes forward (or backwards) and we started doing qualitative analysis, in which we did not find an explicit solution and rather only explain what was happening, but now we are asked to give explicit solutions. Also, maybe I can use the existence and uniqueness theorem and then give the time interval for $t$. Still, it is unclear, given the expression that I wrote in the question I made, how would I find it.